# Css on wordpress

Tags: css, html, wordpress, class

I will try to explain my problem. I am building a blog in Wordpress with the theme Avada and in the home page it will be the flexslider slideshow post. The problem is that i want to change the style of the navigation of bullet and when i change the css to this:

```css
.fusion-flexslider .flex-control-nav {
    position: static;
    background-image:url(http://electroriver.pt/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/sharp-corner13px-000000.png);
    background-position: left bottom;
    position:relative;
    left: auto;
    height:30px;
}
```

it changes also the other types of the blog posts(grid, timeline, large). What i need is to have only the flexslider with this configurations and the others normal.

If you would like to have a look the web is http://www.electroriver.pt

I hope you can help me in this problem.

Many thanks

I keep with the same problem! I think i didn't explain correctly my problem. I have a flexslider post slider and in the end of the slides i want to put the a background image like the configuration that i have in the menu. Inside that image should go the bullets. The problem is when i go the css to change it with the code that i posted in first message all the others featured images in other type of posts grab the same configuration.

I pass all the html of the post content and i have taken out of the page http://wwww.electroriver.pt the css so you can see what is the original version o the slider.~

Thanks.

THE HTML CODE:

```html
<div class="post-content">
    <div class="fusion-flexslider flexslider flexslider-posts"><ul class="slides"><li class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; opacity: 1; display: block; z-index: 2;"><a href="http://electroriver.pt/proin-sodales-quam-nec-ante-sollicits/"><img src="http://electroriver.pt/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Untitled-1.png" alt="Proin Sodales Quam Nec Sollicit" draggable="false"></a><div class="slide-excerpt"><h2><a href="http://electroriver.pt/proin-sodales-quam-nec-ante-sollicits/">Proin Sodales Quam Nec Sollicit</a></h2></div></li><li style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; opacity: 0; display: block; z-index: 1;" class=""><a href="http://electroriver.pt/nunc-tincidunt-elit-non-cursus/"><img src="http://electroriver.pt/wp-content/uploads/revslider/captions_tall/portfolio_1-e1414781863983.jpg" alt="Nunc Tincidunt Elit Cursus" draggable="false"></a><div class="slide-excerpt"><h2><a href="http://electroriver.pt/nunc-tincidunt-elit-non-cursus/">Nunc Tincidunt Elit Cursus</a></h2></div></li></ul><ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-paging"><li><a class="flex-active">1</a></li><li><a class="">2</a></li></ol><ul class="flex-direction-nav"><li><a class="flex-prev" href="#"></a></li><li><a class="flex-next" href="#"></a></li></ul></div><div class="fusion-sep-clear"></div><div class="fusion-separator fusion-full-width-sep sep-none" style="border-color:#e0dede;margin-top:30px;"></div><div class="fusion-blog-shortcode fusion-blog-grid fusion-blog-infinite"><div class="fusion-posts-container posts-container-infinite grid-layout grid-layout-2 isotope" style="position: relative; height: 569px;"><div id="post-209" class="post-209 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-design blog-grid col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="width: 378px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
<div class="post-content-wrapper">      
   
   
   
         <div class="fusion-flexslider flexslider post-slideshow">
          <ul class="slides">
                         <li class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; opacity: 1; display: block; z-index: 2;">
      <div class="image" aria-haspopup="true">
                <img width="800" height="481" src="http://electroriver.pt/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Untitled-1.png" class="attachment-full wp-post-image" alt="Untitled-1" draggable="false">                <div class="image-extras">
         <div class="image-extras-content">
                    <a style="display:inline-block;" class="icon link-icon" href="http://electroriver.pt/proin-sodales-quam-nec-ante-sollicits/">Permalink</a>
                    <a style="display:inline-block;" class="icon gallery-icon" href="http://electroriver.pt/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Untitled-1.png" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery209]" title=""><img style="display:none;" alt="" draggable="false">Gallery</a>
          <h3><a href="http://electroriver.pt/proin-sodales-quam-nec-ante-sollicits/">Proin Sodales Quam Nec Sollicit</a></h3>
          <h4><a href="http://electroriver.pt/category/design/" rel="tag">Design</a></h4>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </li>
              </ul>
   <ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-paging"></ol><ul class="flex-direction-nav"><li><a class="flex-prev flex-disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1"></a></li><li><a class="flex-next flex-disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1"></a></li></ul></div>
   <div class="post-content-container"><h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://electroriver.pt/proin-sodales-quam-nec-ante-sollicits/">Proin Sodales Quam Nec Sollicit</a></h2><div class="entry-meta-single vcard"><p class="entry-meta-details">By <span class="entry-author fn"><a href="http://electroriver.pt/author/joaofreitas/" rel="author">joaofreitas</a></span><span class="meta-separator">|</span><span class="entry-time"><span class="updated" style="display:none;">2014-10-31T18:50:45+00:00</span><time class="published">Julho 31st, 2012</time></span><span class="meta-separator">|</span></p></div><div class="content-sep"></div><div class="excerpt-container strip-html"><p>Quisque ligula ipsum, euismod aturesit vulputate a, ultricies et elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nulla nunc dui, tristique in semper vel, congue sed ligula. Nam dolor […]</p>
</div><p class="entry-read-more"><a href="http://electroriver.pt/proin-sodales-quam-nec-ante-sollicits/">Read More</a></p><p class="entry-comments"><a href="http://electroriver.pt/proin-sodales-quam-nec-ante-sollicits/#respond" title="Comentário em Proin Sodales Quam Nec Sollicit"><i class="fusionicon-bubbles"></i>&nbsp;0</a></p><div class="fusion-clearfix"></div></div><div class="fusion-clearfix"></div></div>
</div><div id="post-207" class="post-207 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-design blog-grid col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="width: 378px; position: absolute; left: 418px; top: 0px;">
<div class="post-content-wrapper">      
   
   
   
         <div class="fusion-flexslider flexslider post-slideshow">
          <ul class="slides">
                         <li class="flex-active-slide" style="width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; opacity: 1; display: block; z-index: 2;">
      <div class="image" aria-haspopup="true">
                <img width="700" height="400" src="http://electroriver.pt/wp-content/uploads/revslider/captions_tall/portfolio_1-e1414781863983.jpg" class="attachment-full wp-post-image" alt="portfolio_1.jpg" draggable="false">                <div class="image-extras">
         <div class="image-extras-content">
                    <a style="display:inline-block;" class="icon link-icon" href="http://electroriver.pt/nunc-tincidunt-elit-non-cursus/">Permalink</a>
                    <a style="display:inline-block;" class="icon gallery-icon" href="http://electroriver.pt/wp-content/uploads/revslider/captions_tall/portfolio_1-e1414781863983.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[gallery207]" title=""><img style="display:none;" alt="" draggable="false">Gallery</a>
          <h3><a href="http://electroriver.pt/nunc-tincidunt-elit-non-cursus/">Nunc Tincidunt Elit Cursus</a></h3>
          <h4><a href="http://electroriver.pt/category/design/" rel="tag">Design</a></h4>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </li>
              </ul>
   <ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-paging"></ol><ul class="flex-direction-nav"><li><a class="flex-prev flex-disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1"></a></li><li><a class="flex-next flex-disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1"></a></li></ul></div>
   <div class="post-content-container"><h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://electroriver.pt/nunc-tincidunt-elit-non-cursus/">Nunc Tincidunt Elit Cursus</a></h2><div class="entry-meta-single vcard"><p class="entry-meta-details">By <span class="entry-author fn"><a href="http://electroriver.pt/author/joaofreitas/" rel="author">joaofreitas</a></span><span class="meta-separator">|</span><span class="entry-time"><span class="updated" style="display:none;">2014-10-31T18:55:07+00:00</span><time class="published">Julho 31st, 2012</time></span><span class="meta-separator">|</span></p></div><div class="content-sep"></div><div class="excerpt-container strip-html"><p>Quisque ligula ipsum, euismod a vulputate a, ultricies et elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nulla nunc dui, tristique in semper vel, congue sed ligula. Nam dolor […]</p>
</div><p class="entry-read-more"><a href="http://electroriver.pt/nunc-tincidunt-elit-non-cursus/">Read More</a></p><p class="entry-comments"><a href="http://electroriver.pt/nunc-tincidunt-elit-non-cursus/#respond" title="Comentário em Nunc Tincidunt Elit Cursus"><i class="fusionicon-bubbles"></i>&nbsp;0</a></p><div class="fusion-clearfix"></div></div><div class="fusion-clearfix"></div></div>
</div><div class="fusion-clearfix"></div></div></div><div class="fusion-sep-clear"></div><div class="fusion-separator fusion-full-width-sep sep-none" style="border-color:#e0dede;margin-top:40px;margin-bottom:40px;"></div>
       </div>
```

Comment: Are you saying that the bullets are styled differently on other pages as well, and you want to target JUST the bullets on the home page?

Comment: Please give your question a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need to add a specific ID (or class) for this slider, so will not affect any other element.

```
#specific-id.fusion-flexslider .flex-control-nav {
  background-image: url(http://electroriver.pt/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/sharp-corner13px-000000.png);
  background-position: left bottom;
  position: relative;
  left: auto;
  height: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you wanted to style just the first set of slider bullets, you'll need to add more to your selector. So if you want to target just the first slider, you could do something like this:

```
.post-content .fusion-flexslider:first-child .flex-control-nav{
    /* Styles Go Here */
}
```

This uses the :first-child selector to select only the first instance of something inside of it's parent element.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

Comment: Hy joe it didn't work. I have try to explain better my problem again. thanks

Answer (score -2):

Your code:

```
`.fusion-flexslider .flex-control-nav {
position: static;
background-image:url(http://electroriver.pt/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/sharp-corner13px-000000.png);
background-position: left bottom;
position:relative;
left: auto;
height:30px;
}   `
```

Has a **`** before and after it. Remove that and your styles (the grid and everything else) should be fine again.

**EDIT: It appears it was a mistake on the asker's part by accident.**
Regardless, you're targeting the entire nav (not the dots) entirely and the image you've supplied is just a large black box. If you're trying to target the dots specifically, use this: `.flex-control-paging li a`

Also, if you want to target the home page only, you have the class `home` in your body tag. You can use `.home .flex-control-paging li a` to target the bullets on the home page within the slider.

Comment: The code itself on the provided link did not have those symbols in it. I'm guessing it was a mistake when writing his initial post.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that was the initial reason to why his styles were messed up because he had ` that by accident in his styles. Apparently he just had that in his initial post.

Comment: Yes it was a mistake sorry!!! But i keep with the same problem! I think i didn't explain correctly my problem.

Comment: Try mocking up an image for me to see what you want.

Comment: I have try to explain better the issue again. Have a look and see if you can understand what a i want.